# Adding query results to an existing csv with powershell

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell.  I am trying to automate the importation of student test scores into our student management system.  We receive a csv file containing test data from multiple users.  I need to convert the student ID from the csv file into the student ID our system uses. Students are allowed to take a test multiple times.  The sample file did not include the IntID field I added it while trying to find a solution.

Sample CSV file:

```
ID, Test, Score, Date, IntID
1234, 51, 90, 6/20/2018
1234, 51, 92, 7/15/2018
2345, 67, 95, 7/18/2018
3456, 77, 84, 7/10/2018
```

What I have so far:

```
add-type -path "D:\app\oracle\client\ODP.NET\bin\2.x\oracle.dataaccess.dll"
$con = new-object oracle.dataaccess.client.oracleconnection("user id=user;password=xxxxx;data source=proddb")
$con.open()

$file = import-csv D:\TestLoad\scores.csv
$file.ID | foreach-object {
$cmd = $con.CreateCommand()
$cmd.CommandText = "select user_id from user where user_ssn = '" + $_ + "' "

$rdr = $cmd.ExecuteReader()
if ($rdr.Read()) {
    $rdr.GetDecimal(0) | select *,@{Name='IntID';Expression={$rdr.GetDecimal(0)}} | export-csv D:\TestLoad\scores.csv -notypeinformation -append -force
}
}
$con.Close()
```

My results:

```
ID, Test, Score, Date, IntID
1234, 51, 90, 6/20/2018
1234, 51, 92, 7/15/2018
2345, 67, 95, 7/18/2018
3456, 77, 84, 7/10/2018
,,,,"73711"
,,,,"73711"
,,,,"96255"
,,,,"41201"
```

I feel like I am missing something simple but I am currently stumped as to how to get my IntID results to line up properly.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the IntId header out of the source file, that will only risk confusing Import-Csv when the lines below don't have commas for that column and things don't match up.

Iterating over the IDs alone, when you do `$file.ID | foreach-object {` loses all the original column data. You try to select it again later with `select *,...` but you try to feed `$rdr.GetDecimal(0) | select-object` and the output of `getDecimal()` has nothing of the original CSV data for the `select` to work on.

The CSV handling in PowerShell is very opinionated, and the kind of flow you need is:

Import-Csv -> objects in the pipeline -> add new property to each object with IntId name/value -> export to *new* csv, or overwrite, but not `-append`ing new lines.

I think something like this approach will work:

```
Add-Type -path "D:\app\oracle\client\ODP.NET\bin\2.x\oracle.dataaccess.dll"

$con = new-object oracle.dataaccess.client.oracleconnection("user id=user;password=xxxxx;data source=proddb")
$con.open()

import-csv D:\TestLoad\scores.csv | foreach-object {

    $cmd = $con.CreateCommand()
    $cmd.CommandText = "select user_id from user where user_ssn = '" + $_.Id + "' "

    $rdr = $cmd.ExecuteReader()

    if ($rdr.Read())
    {

        # $_ being an object representing the current line of the CSV
        $_ | Add-Member -NotePropertyName 'IntId' -NotePropertyValue $rdr.GetDecimal(0) -PassThru
    }
} | Export-Csv D:\TestLoad\scores2.csv -notypeinformation -append -force

$con.Close()
```

Comment: Yes that was what I needed.  Thank you very much for the help, especially showing me what I was doing wrong.  I appreciate you sharing your knowledge.